# How can I get letter spacing?

Tags: spacing, emphasis, letterspacing

Letter spacing is a special kind of emphasis often used in combination with blackletter fonts. A letter spaced has 0.125 em spaces between its characters, but some ligatures are preserved. For example: »B ä ck e r ſt r a ß e« How can I get letter spacing with (La)TeX?

Comment: The `soul` package has some features along these lines, but I don't know if it's quite what you are looking for.

Comment: Just for clarity: Sperrsatz (German) = [Letter spacing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis_%28typography%29#Letter_spacing)

Comment: Frederic Goudy: "A man who would letter space blackletter would steal sheep."

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Thank you for the correct term.

Comment: While I'm not a native speaker, I'm not sure if "letter spacing" can be used to refer to this markup specifically, although it undoubtedly describes it appropriately. I find the "spacing out" mentioned in the Wikipedia article more precise. "Letter spacing" sounds like "Buchstabenabstand" ("distance between letters") of any kind, including the normal, unaltered. Any native speaker opinion on this (potentially with blackletter typography experience)? (And thanks for the hint on the Wiki article, the part about the mandatory and optional ligatures is quite interesting!)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With the `microtype` package and pdfTeX, you just need to enclose the text which you want to emphasize in a `\textls` command. You can adjust the amount of letterspacing (Sperrsatz) globally by adding `letterspace=125` to the package options or, alternatively, locally by providing it as an optional argument to the `\textls` command (in multiples of 1/1000 em).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage[letterspace=125]{microtype}

\begin{document}
\frakfamily
\textls{B\"ackerstra\ss e}
\textls[50]{B\"ackerstra\ss e}
\end{document}
```

If you are not interested in the other features of `microtype` such as margin kerning, you can instead load the `letterspace` package with the same option.

Comment: Works like a charm and even preserves the ligatures.

Comment: Is this any different from `\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=12.5}` ?

Comment: Note: this does not preserve all ligatures. See [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/709456/250119) for details.

Answer (score 4):

[This page](http://unifraktur.sourceforge.net/letterspacing.html) from the UniFraktur project goes into detail about letterspacing and shows what to do for XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [soulutf8](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/soulutf8) package and its `\sodef` command to define a new command to get the desired letter spacing; to mantain a ligature you can use `\mbox` inside the argument of the newly defined command:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\sodef\Sp{}{.125em}{1em plus1em}{2em plus.1em minus.1em}


\begin{document}
\Sp{Bäcker\mbox{ßt}raße}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The advantage of using the microtype package in the case of letterspacing with Fraktur is that it preserves the special German ligatures automatically. No need to remember to place various letter combinations inside mbox-es.

Answer (score 3):

LuaLaTeX solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\letterspaced{Latin Modern Roman}[LetterSpace=50]
\begin{document}
Hello world

{\letterspaced Hello world}

Hello world
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

---

There's an alternative solution that does not require defining a font family, but it's [much slower](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197471/250119).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\fontspec{Latin Modern Roman}  % set the default font https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/643918/250119

Hello world fi

{
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=50}
Hello world fi
}

{
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=50,Ligatures={NoCommon, NoDiscretionary}}  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103242/250119
Hello world fi
}

Hello world fi

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

- First line is normal text,
- second line is LetterSpace,
- third line is LetterSpace with ligatures disabled,
- forth line is back to normal text.

How much slower?

I compare two documents with the following changes:

```
\csname prg_replicate:nn\endcsname{200}{
{\letterspaced Hello world}

}
```

versus

```
\csname prg_replicate:nn\endcsname{200}{
{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=50} Hello world}

}
```

The time taken are 0m4.137s and 0m1.254s respectively. So that evaluates to 14ms per usage, or: for every 70 usages of `\addfontfeature`, your compilation time slows down by a second.

Comment: Cool idea!  Note that for proper letter spacing in German, only some ligatures are preserved while others are split.  Specifically, ligatures ſt, ch, ck, and tz are preserved, others are lost.