# Is using \addfontfeatures (much?) less efficient than defining a \newfontface?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec

Consider the following file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Numbers={Lining,Proportional},Ligatures=Common]{EB Garamond}
\newfontface\garamondoldstylenumbers[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},Ligatures=Common]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

EB Garamond 123

\typeout{1st use of \addfontfeatures}
{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}}EB Garamond 123\par}
\typeout{2nd use of \addfontfeatures}
{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}}EB Garamond 123\par}

\typeout{1st use of \garamondoldstylenumbers}
{\garamondoldstylenumbers EB Garamond 123\par}
\typeout{2nd use of \garamondoldstylenumbers}
{\garamondoldstylenumbers EB Garamond 123\par}

\end{document}
```

If this is compiled under either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, examining the log file shows messages along the lines of

```
.................................................
. Font family 'EBGaramond(2)' created for font 'EB Garamond' with options
. [Numbers={Lining,Proportional},Ligatures=Common,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}].
. 
. This font family consists of the following shapes:
.
```

etc. after *both* uses of `\addfontfeatures`, but not after using `\garamondoldstylenumbers`. (Naturally, similar messages occurs in when `\setmainfont` and `\newfontface` are processed in the preamble.)

There will be some performance hit from parsing the options to `\addfontfeatures`. But is there a performance hit beyond this, because `fontspec` seems to be defining the font anew each time?

The only relevant thing I can find in the fontspec manual says "For cases when a specific font with a specific feature set is going to be re-used many times in a document, it is inefficient to keep calling `\fontspec` for every use. While the `\fontspec` command does not define a new font instance after the first call, the feature options must still be parsed and processed." I would assume that `\addfontfeatures` uses the `\fontspec` command, but I don't know the details of the implementation.

(I will be typesetting a long document that will require frequent use of both the italic and swashed italic of a commercial font: I have used old style numbers and EB Garamond in the example because it is freely available. Naturally, I would normally define a macro for `\addfontfeatures{...}`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My development version of `fontspec` might be out of sync with the current TeX Live version on this matter — I know I recently fixed an issue that involved `\addfontfeatures` incorrectly creating new font families.

In my development version, the `2nd use of \addfontfeatures` line in the log file doesn't lead into the ‘Font Family (…) created’ message. However, I did notice when browsing the code that there could be some significant improvements in how early the pre-existence of a font family is checked.

The short answer is: if `fontspec` is behaving correctly then `\addfontfeatures` should be somewhat but not ‘much’ less efficient than `\newfontface`. But external benchmarking is recommended `:)`

Comment: Thank you for the authoritative answer. I just updated TeX Live, and the fix you mentioned is now in effect and I am no longer seeing the extra "Font Family ... created" messages. Thank you for the reassurance in the last paragraph.