# Letter spacing and ligatures

Tags: microtype, ligatures, letterspacing

Is there a way to slightly increase letter spacing (tracking) using microtype package and **not** to lose the ligatures—especially **not** those starting with ‘f’—other then putting all the “fi“ and “fl“ and “ffl” into `\lslig{}`?

MWE:

```
%%%! lualatex
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\usepackage[
    protrusion = true,
    expansion = true,
    tracking = true,
]{microtype}
\begin{document}
\SetTracking{encoding = *, shape = *}{1}\lsstyle
fikce a fiflena
\end{document}
```

[image: broken ligatures with kerning]

Example with ligatures protected by `\lslig`:

```
%%%! lualatex
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\usepackage[
    protrusion = true,
    expansion = true,
    tracking = true,
]{microtype}
\begin{document}
\SetTracking{encoding = *, shape = *}{1}\lsstyle
\lslig{fi}kce a \lslig{fi}\lslig{fl}ena
\end{document}
```

[image: protected ligatures]

Comment: Could you give me an MWE where `microtype` is breaking up ligatures?

Comment: can you show this example also *with* the ligatures set with `\lslig`, please?  with the spacing shown, the spaces between the unligatured pairs and what's next to them looks smaller than the spaces resulting from removal of ligatures, so it would be good to have a comparison.

Comment: @barbara: Sure, in a minute.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible with the current version of `microtype`. Note that ligatures will only be broken up with `luatex`, not with `pdftex`, where you may choose which ligatures should be kept. The next version will allow this also for `luatex`. Using `xetex` is not an option for you?

Comment: @Robert: Thx for your answer. xetex is not an option: the project is too big and it's been already decided earlier that we shall use luatex. However, how would xetex help me? The documentation says microtype doesn't support tracking with xetex at all.

Comment: with xetex, you could use `fontspec`'s `LetterSpace` feature.

Comment: @Robert: Any idea when this new version of `microtype`, that will allow to choose ligatures to keep in `luatex`, should be available?

Comment: It's on CTAN now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by a new version of `microtype` ...

Comment: Question about general letterspacing feature: [emphasis - How can I get letter spacing? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17185/how-can-i-get-letter-spacing)