# Ligatures are not preserved by \textls letter spacing

Tags: microtype, ligatures, letterspacing

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
fi \textls[1]{fi}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Problem: the ligature is lost. How do I keep the ligature (preferably without manually inserting `\lslig`, since the documentation of microtype says ligature will be preserved automatically)?

Compiler is PDFLaTeX.

I found the related question [Letter spacing and ligatures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304426/250119) , but it states that it will be resolved in a newer version of microtype, and my microtype version is definitely new enough (that question is 7 years ago) --- my `microtype.sty` file contains:

```tex
\ProvidesPackage
  {microtype}
  [2023/03/13 v3.1a
   Micro-typographical refinements
   (RS)]
```

Comment: The documentation says *The default settings disable ligatures for the character ‘f’ only, i.e., ‘ff’,
‘fi’, ffi’, etc.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I agree with the advice [@egreg gives in his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709457/111381). Nevertheless:

The default tracking settings (in `microtype.cfg`) are as follows:

```
\SetTracking
  [ name         = default,
    no ligatures = {f} ]
  { encoding     = {OT1,T1,T2A,LY1,OT4,QX,EU2,TU} }
  { }
```

which will disable only ligatures starting with `f`: e.g., `fl`, `fi`, `ffl`, but not, for example, `--` or `` !` ``. You may change this to:

```
\SetTracking
  [ load         = default,
    no ligatures = {X} ]
  { encoding     = {OT1,T1,T2A,LY1,OT4,QX,EU2,TU} }
  { }
```

The first line is just to avoid a warning about settings overwriting existing ones. The `X` in the `no ligatures` key is a dirty hack: since an empty value would be interpreted as "disable all ligatures", we specify a letter that will probably never start a ligature, leaving all others untouched. (microtype should probably allow keywords such as `all` and `none` to prevent the ambiguity of an empty value.)

Comment: Is there any difference to type out the list of all encoding instead of just `encoding=*`?

Comment: @user202729 yes, the asterisk means (somewhat counterintuitively) "default", not "any". That said, if you're only using one encoding in your document, it would be fine to write `encoding=*` instead of, say, `encoding=OT1`.

Answer (score 9):

1. Don't letterspace lowercase (unless you want to reproduce some old German text).
2. Ligatures generally avoid clashes when some letterforms are next to each other, so they *should* be split when letterspacing.

<sup>Note about point 1. Fraktur has no other way to express emphasis except letterspacing; German typography has used letterspacing also for “Antiqua” to follow that tradition. I've also seen Russian texts where letterspacing is used for emphasis.</sup>

I don't think anybody would want

[image]

instead of

[image]

Comment: This may be a good advice if the user want good typography, but what if the user wants [bad typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/413918/250119)?