# LuaLatex removes ligatures with LetterSpace

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, letterspacing

If I compile the following (M)WE with LuaLatex, all the possible ligatures are removed. This does not happen with the standard font or if I remove the `\defaultfontfeatures{LetterSpace=1}` or if I set it to `0`. Also, removing `babel` leads to the correct output, replacing it with polyglossia does not help. Why are the letters missing?

---

I've tested this behaviour with more fonts than those that are listed below. The result was always the same. Calibri font comes with MS Windows/Office, Linux Libertine is the TTF from the sourceforge page, Myriad and Minion are from the Adobe Reader.

---

My OS and LaTeX version:

Windows 10 64-bit

```
>tlmgr --version 
tlmgr revision 39298 (2016-01-07 03:44:29 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: C:/texlive/2015
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2015
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{LetterSpace=1}
\newfontfamily\myCalibri{Calibri}
\newfontfamily\myLibertine{Linux Libertine}
\newfontfamily\myMyriad{Myriad Pro}
\newfontfamily\myMinion{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}
{ Standard \par Affe \par Angriffe \par Hanfling \par \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \par }
{\myCalibri Calibri \par Affe \par Angriffe \par Hanfling \par \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \par }
{\myLibertine Linux Libertine \par Affe \par Angriffe \par Hanfling \par  \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \par }
{\myMyriad Myriad Pro \par Affe \par Angriffe \par Hanfling \par \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \par }
{\myMinion Minion Pro \par Affe \par Angriffe \par Hanfling \par \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \par }
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

Comment: No problem if I remove the call to `babel`. This needs investigation.

Comment: @egreg So you were able to reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: Yes, I was; I removed Calibri because I don't have it and loaded `Linux Libertine O`, but that was all. And with `ngerman` active the behavior is exactly as you showed.

Comment: See https://github.com/phi-gamma/luaotfload/commit/43f70e0cb460dc46391664191f56e07b281e5698

Comment: @Herbert I'm not sure it's the same phenomenon; the letters are present if `ngerman` is changed into `english`.

Comment: With texlive2016 it works fine (for the fonts I have), in texlive 2015 I too can see missing ligatures. The problem can also be seen with english if one add a hyphenation point (`\hyphenation{Angrif-fe}`), and it disappears in ngerman if one remove the hyphenation point. (`\hyphenation{Angriffe}`).

Comment: The problem is the node mode as can be seen in the fix from Hans.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is solved by using an updated setup.

Comment: Question about general letterspacing feature: [emphasis - How can I get letter spacing? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17185/how-can-i-get-letter-spacing)